# Create new temp table from old temp table using Create As Select

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am doing some testing and unable to create a new temp table from old temp table.
This is my code.

**1st table**

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp1 ( Col1 Money, Col2 Money );
```

This works fine.

**2nd table**

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp2 
AS (Select Col1, Col2 
From #Temp1)
```

This errors with

> Incorrect syntax near '('.

I am following [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/tables/create_table2.php) link to learn, which has the following code

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM old_table);
```

This is almost the same as mine, except mine are temp tables.

I tried using

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp2 
AS (Select Col1, Col2 
From tempdb..#Temp1)
```

to make sure it finds the path of the temp table

but it gives me

> Database name 'tempdb' ignored, referencing object in tempdb.

Is there a different way to do it when both are temp tables ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CREATE AS` syntax is not valid for SQL Server. That site doesn't say which RDMBS that is for so maybe it is more generic and works on others. Here is the MSDN page for [CREATE TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx).

Creating tables on the fly can be done with the [INTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) clause of a `SELECT` statement.

If you want to copy the table (schema *and* data):

```
 SELECT *
 INTO #Temp2
 FROM #Temp1
```

If you only want to create a similar table (schema only):

```
 SELECT *
 INTO #Temp2
 FROM #Temp1
 WHERE 1 = 0;
```